# What do the screens say after you are set free?

Tags: video-games, superhot

In the video game *Superhot*, after

> being uploaded and freed from your useless, disposable body,

there is some tiny red text against a black background that shows up for a few seconds on the monitors. **What does it say?**

Comment: A screenshot would be useful

Comment: @Jenayah I’m trying to make one small enough to upload right now :-)

Comment: Is this truly on topic?

Comment: @DJSpicy why do you think it wouldn’t be?

Comment: @Stormblessed because its a video game that's not very SFFish

Comment: @DJSpicy it’s definitely SF. Have you played it? ***{SPOILERS}*** You kill your body in the real world and your mind is uploaded to a computer.

Comment: @Stormblessed Yes, although that's not exactly how I interpreted it. I always saw it as you're a guy playing a VR game in his home, seeing as after every few areas you go back and to get back in you put on a VR headset.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Riffing off of [Valorum's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/216973/23243), [guru meditation](https://www.definitions.net/definition/guru+meditation) is a reference to a famous Amiga error. From *The New Hacker's Dictionary*:

> Amiga equivalent of panic in Unix (sometimes just called a guru or guru event). When the system crashes, a cryptic message of the form “GURU MEDITATION #XXXXXXXX.YYYYYYYY” may appear, indicating what the problem was. An Amiga guru can figure things out from the numbers. Sometimes a guru event must be followed by a Vulcan nerve pinch.This term is (no surprise) an in-joke from the earliest days of the Amiga. An earlier product of the Amiga corporation was a device called a ‘Joyboard’ which was basically a plastic board built onto a joystick-like device; it was sold with a skiing game cartridge for the Atari game machine. It is said that whenever the prototype OS crashed, the system programmer responsible would calm down by concentrating on a solution while sitting cross-legged on a Joyboard trying to keep the board in balance. This position resembled that of a meditating guru. Sadly, the joke was removed fairly early on (but there's a well-known patch to restore it in more recent versions).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the Amiga connection.

Comment: @Darren: My brother got me a paper copy of the *Hacker's Dictionary* at a tender age.

Answer (score 11):

It says

> **Software failure. Press left mouse button to continue.
>
>            Guru Meditation #00000004.48454C50**

I managed to freeze-frame it on this ["ending" video](https://youtu.be/e7fLJdqY8mg?t=399)

[image]

As @Fuzzyboots has [pointed out in his answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/216979/20774), the words relate to an (old) easter egg [error message used on Commodore Amiga computers](https://www.definitions.net/definition/guru+meditation). In this instance, a software failure that would require a reboot, the numbers 48454C50 spelling out "***help***" in ASCII code, which signifies a fatal error that the computer can't diagnose.

Comment: Not an "easter egg". More like a "sudden rage event". That's the cost of not shelling out for a proper MMU.

Comment: Animated gif [here](http://www.geekometry.com/2017/09/amiga-guru-meditation-error-animated-gif/) ... `#00000004.4E454C50` means that CPU hit an illegal instruction in the task that can be found at address 0x4E454C50. That's too high an address for a Motorola 68000 though, which would only go to 0xFFFFFF

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: The second number is almost certainly 4**8**454C50, which spells out "HELP" in ASCII code. It's what the Amiga would show if it couldn't determine the relevant address for some reason (e.g. because the error handling code itself crashed and the machine had to reboot before displaying a deferred error box).

Answer (score 7):

[image: screenshot of black screen with red text]

> Software failure. Press left mouse button to continue.
>
> Guru Meditation ?000000004.48454C50

I'm not sure what the `?` is. Possibly a block `▊` or a hash `#`